# Accessing elements from a list using an anonymous function

Tags: list, erlang, anonymous-function

So, lets say I have a list of functions such as `[(+3), (*10), (+50)]` and a value `1` I am trying to create a function in Erlang that uses an anonymous function access and apply every function to the value passed in by the user.

In Haskell I would do:

`mapFuncs funcs val = map(\x -> x val) funcs`

However in Erlang I am not sure how to apply every element of the list of functions to the value that is passed in by the user:

```
mapFuncs(Funcs, Val) -> lists:map(fun(X)->X(Val)).
```

Input: `[(+3), (*10), (+50)] , 1`

Desired Output:
`[4, 10, 51]`

I appreciate any suggestions on how to implement this and generally how to access elements of a list that was passed in using an Anonymous function.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use lists:map or lists comprehension. Each anonymous function is taken from the list as a Variable and it is called passing the value.

Using lists map

```
mapFuncs(Funcs, Val) -> 
    lists:map(fun(Fun)->Fun(Val) end, Funcs).
```

Using more powerful list comprehension

```
mapFuncs(Funcs, Val) -> 
    [Fun(Val) || Fun <- Funcs].
```

The function is called as follows

```
mapFuncs([fun(Val) -> Val + 3 end,
          fun(Val) -> Val * 10 end,
          fun(Val) -> Val + 50 end], 1).
```

Here each element in the list is an anonymous function.

Comment: +1, Thanks for the reply. How would you call this function? When I try to use my input data, I get a syntax error. `mapFuncs(1, [(+3),(*10),(+50)]).`

Comment: Already written in the answer `mapFuncs([fun(Val) -> Val + 3 end,
          fun(Val) -> Val * 10 end,
          fun(Val) -> Val + 50 end], 1).` You need to send a list of anonymous functions as the input.

Answer (score 0):

You could write something using list comprehension.

```
-module(mylists).
-export([mapList/2]).

mapList(ListFuns, Val) ->
   [ Func(Val) || Func <- ListFuns].
```

The `Func <- ListFuns` is the generator, this creates the list of functions for the list comprehension. The `Func(Val)` is the result, saying we want to apply the functions to the value passed into the original function of `mapList`.